# xsl variable - only filtered data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have set of unique parts (part_number defined with part nodes. Those parts can be used many times and each occurane ist defined by part_occurance node which is
linked by part value to part id.

```
<data>
<part id="part_id_01">
    <part_number>number_01</part_number>
</part>
<part id="part_id_03">
    <part_number>number_18</part_number>
</part>
<part id="part_id_04">
    <part_number>number_12</part_number>
</part>
<part id="part_id_05">
    <part_number>number_13</part_number>
</part>
<part_occurence id="occurence_id_01">
    <part>part_id_03</part>
    <name>test_0</name>
</part_occurence>
<part_occurence id="occurence_id_02">
    <part>part_id_03</part>
    <name>test_1</name>
</part_occurence>
<part_occurence id="occurence_id_03">
    <part>part_id_01</part>
    <name>test_2</name>
</part_occurence>
<part_occurence id="occurence_id_04">
    <part>part_id_04</part>
    <name>test_3</name>
</part_occurence>
<part_occurence id="occurence_id_05">
    <part>part_id_03</part>
    <name>test_4</name>
</part_occurence>
<part_occurence id="occurence_id_06">
    <part>part_id_03</part>
    <name>test_4</name>
</part_occurence>
</data>
```

This set contains all occurances:

```
<xsl:variable name="occurrence_List1" select="part_occurrence" />
```

How to get this variable containing occurences but excluded all occurences with part_number for example 'number_18'

My XML is very large and created dynamically and I will keep at this variable only filtered data for later for-each use. Because I go later many times throw this variable i want keep it small as possible for speed reason...Sorry for bad my english :)

This is my xsl-file now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pxslt="file://pxslt.py" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:key name="k1" match="part" use="@id"/>
<xsl:template match="/data">
<xsl:variable name="part_list" select="part" />
<xsl:variable name="occurrence_List1" select="part_occurrence[not(key('k1', part)/part_number = 'number_18')]" />
<!--<xsl:variable name="occurrence_List1" select="part_occurence" />-->
<test>
<xsl:for-each select="$occurrence_List1">
    <part>
        <xsl:variable name="idx" select="part"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="part"><xsl:value-of select="part" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="part_name"><xsl:value-of select="$part_list[@id=$idx]/part_number" /></xsl:attribute>
    </part>
</xsl:for-each>
</test>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the result is empty. :(

When I try without filtering I get:

```
<test xmlns:pxslt="file://pxslt.py" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <part part="part_id_03" part_name="number_18"/>
  <part part="part_id_03" part_name="number_18"/>
  <part part="part_id_01" part_name="number_01"/>
  <part part="part_id_04" part_name="number_12"/>
  <part part="part_id_03" part_name="number_18"/>
  <part part="part_id_03" part_name="number_18"/>
</test>
```

Comment: Where will the value "number_18" come from?

Comment: it comes from node 'part'. It is a value from 'part_number'

Comment: I meant the value "number_18" that you use in order to exclude occurrences; will it be hard-coded into the stylesheet, as shown in your example?

Comment: exactlly... i try to parse KBL (Harness Description List) http://www.ecad-if.de/kbl.html and there are some dummy parts which must be filtered. In that case i try to remove all occurances with part_name = 'number_18'

Answer (score 0):

Define a key

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="part" use="@id"/>
```

then use `<xsl:variable name="occurrence_List1" select="part_occurence[not(key('k1', part)/part_number = 'number_18')] />`.

Here is a complete example based on your provided samples:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pxslt="file://pxslt.py" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:key name="k1" match="part" use="@id"/>
<xsl:template match="/data">
<xsl:variable name="part_list" select="part" />
<xsl:variable name="occurrence_List1" select="part_occurence[not(key('k1', part)/part_number = 'number_18')]" />
<!--<xsl:variable name="occurrence_List1" select="part_occurence" />-->
<test>
<xsl:for-each select="$occurrence_List1">
    <part part="{part}" part_name="{key('k1', part)/part_number}"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</test>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Watch out for the spelling of English names, your sample XML has "part_occurence" while your path selects or tries to select "part_occurrence", based on my spelling I think, I have now used the wrong spelling "occurence" in the paths to make sure the XML elements with the wrong spelling are selected.

Comment: but i only know value 'number_18' at this point. Ids are generated automatically and dynamically...

Comment: @walko1234, see the edit, I think I first misunderstood the relationship, but with my edit the comparison is based on `number_18`.

Comment: @walko1234, see my edit, it is simply a spelling problem, the XML input has an incorrect spelling of a name which I did not notice when defining the variable.

Comment: @walko1234 Please accept this as an answer if it solved your problem.